# How to change the font used inside the chunks when knitting as tuffte_handout pdf?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, tufte

I am working in a book, using R and the Tufte library.
I am using the following YAML for each .Rmd Chapter:

````
---
title: "Chapter 2: A First Linear Program"
header-includes:
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{caption}
output:
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
  highlight: monochrome
  tufte::tufte_html: default
  tufte::tufte_book:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

\pagestyle{headings}


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tufte)
library(tint)
library(knitr)
library(gridExtra)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy = F)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(width = 30)
```
````

And the following one is the YAML for the index .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Operations Research Using R<br />"
author: "Timothy R. Anderson"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography: ["Master4Bookdowns.bib"]
---

# Preface {-}
```

I have tried different options like adding the sansfont and mainfont in YAML:

```
output:
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
  highlight: monochrome
  sansfont: Calibri Light
  mainfont: Calibri Light
```

But it didn't change the font inside the chunk, only the text outside.

---

Here a simpler example document showing my attempt to change `monofont` as suggested in the comments:

````
---
title: "Chapter 2: A First Linear Program"
header-includes:
\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{caption}
output:
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: TRUE
    number_sections: true
  highlight: monochrome
  monofont: Times New Roman
  tufte::tufte_html: default
  tufte::tufte_book:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

\pagestyle{headings}


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tufte)
library(tint)
library(knitr)
library(gridExtra)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy = F)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(width = 30)
```

This is an example, where we can see that text in the book is affected by the use of command
monofont: Times New Roman in the YAML. However, we can see that next chunk, the oucome when generating the tuffte_handout pdf is using a different font and also using multiple colors (no only black as in the main body).


```{r base_case_no_pipes_step_4}

model0d <- c("example", 6 + 2 <= 2000) 
#fabrication
model0e <- c("example", 8 + 6 <= 2000)  
#assembly    
```
````

Comment: Please condense and reformat your question appropriately.

Comment: I have reduced some redundant paragraphs. It may still look a bit long, but I wanted to show what I have already done. Please let me know if it still looks too long. Thanks

Comment: You might try changing `monofont`.

Comment: I tried also using monofont, but it affects only to the main font in the book as well, not the font inside the chunks.

Comment: @monzarrate I find it very surprising that `monofont` should change the mainfont of the document. Without a real [mcve] it is impossible for me the help further.

Comment: @RalfStubner, I have added a short example to test. just copy+paste the code and you will see in the outcome that the main text has a different font than chunk text. Additionally, chunk text has several colors for the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bring the YAML headers to the right level:

- `monofont` et al. are top-level headers
- `highlight` is below the output format, not below `output`

The following example uses "Times New Roman" for the code block and XeLaTeX's default font (Latin Modern) for the main text. You can change that with `mainfont`. In addition, there is no syntax highlighting:

````
---
title: "Chapter 2: A First Linear Program"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{caption}
monofont: Times New Roman
output:
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: TRUE
    number_sections: true
    highlight: monochrome
  tufte::tufte_html: default
  tufte::tufte_book:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

\pagestyle{headings}


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tufte)
library(tint)
library(knitr)
library(gridExtra)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy = F)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(width = 30)
```

This is an example, where we can see that text in the book is affected by the use of command
monofont: Times New Roman in the YAML. However, we can see that next chunk, the oucome when generating the tuffte_handout pdf is using a different font and also using multiple colors (no only black as in the main body).


```{r base_case_no_pipes_step_4}

model0d <- c("example", 6 + 2 <= 2000) 
#fabrication
model0e <- c("example", 8 + 6 <= 2000)  
#assembly

```
````

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked well when I use the tufte_handout output for a single chapter after following your recommendation. By another hand, and I guess I should open a new question, because for any reason, when I combine the entire book (it has 9 chapters) and I knit it using bookdown::bookdown_tuftebook2 the colors are still there.

Comment: @monzarrate Do you have `highlight: monochrome` in the `output.bookdown::bookdown_tuftebook2` section? BTW, the conventional way to say “thank you” on SO is to accept/upvote answers.

Comment: Thanks, @Ralf Stubner. I will open a new post for the new doubt when building the book.

Comment: if you have the chance, and could have a look at the newer post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297474/how-to-change-the-font-colour-used-inside-the-chunks-when-building-a-tufte-book and let me know if you have any suggestion, I would appreciate it.